# Cassandra/Parquet union RDD

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am just getting started with spark-cassandra connector and am running into the following issue: I have a dataset that is partially in cassandra, partially in HDFS(same exact schema). I would like to create a single UnionRDD of the two sets and proceed from there.

The code I have so far goes like this:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.parquetFile("foo.parquet");
JavaRDD cassandraRDD = (JavaRDD)javaFuntions(sc).cassandraTable("foo_ks","foo_table");
DataFrame cassandraDF = sqlContext.applySchema(cassandraRDD,df.schema());
```

I am getting a runtime error saying that CassandraRow cannot be cast to spark.sql.Row, coming from the applySchema call...which is not all to surprising. What would be the proper way to get this to work? (my ultimate goal is to union df & cassandraDF).

I am trying this with Spark 1.3.1 and a build from cassandra-spark's master branch.

Comment: If you are getting an exception then you first print the schema and compare with cassandraRDD's fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be write a map function which will take

1. Cassandra Row
2. Source schema object
3. Target schema object

This map function will

1. Read a cassandra row using source schema (and handle issues, like fill missing column, suppress rows with certain data quality issues etc)
2. Translate cassandra schema to spark sql schema (this is a static mapping b/w cassandra types to sql types)
3. Return SQL Row object with target schema

So, you should be able to do llike

cDF = cRDD.map(c2r).createDataFrame() // map will return row so no applySchema needed here

Basically, I would suggest to handle the conversion using a single function. Once you "create" a DF from cassandra data, you can do union with any other DF.

Comment: Thanks ayan -- I was hoping to NOT have to write c2r by hand as my row has 70+ fields...which are already typed in cassandra anyway. I'll mark your answer as accepted as I don't think there is a simpler way either...

Comment: Well, you may not need to do it "by hand". You can open a separate JDBC connection and get the schema information from Cassandra. Then you can use that in c2r. This way you would not need to change the code even if your schema changes. The core point it, yes, we have to tell spark about the schema. Btw, new Cassandra connectors are out, or so I have heard. You can/should take a look....